# C++ Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Debug issue (Cannot find or open the PDB file.)

Tags: c++, debugging

Very new to coding as well as compilers. I have recently started learning C++ and have been attempting to use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 as my compiler. Unfortunately every time I try to compile even the simplest of programs, I continuously get the same error. I have looked for other solutions but everything seems to be outdated showing either 2010 or 2013 Microsoft VS. I have tried editing the debug options, "Load dll exports (Native Only) as I saw that that could have been a possible solutions but that also did not solve the issue. If anyone can help me out it would be very much appreciated, also if you could explain the issue as simply as possible it would also be much appreciated as I said before, I know very little about coding or the compilers yet.

Comment: Just to be clear... what pdb files cannot be opened? Your program ones or the ones from the system DLLs?

Answer (score 0):

1. In Debug -> Options -> Symbols check if you have folder where you have PDBs and Microsoft Server. Also create folder for Cache, and have "Load all modules" checked
2. Get Debug -> Windows -> Modules, and start app step by step. Go inside until you see you app in Modules, right click on your module and try to force loading symbols.